# JavaScript - getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, nodelist, getelementsbyname

I was trying to learn some JavaScript and make a modal for my webpage through this tutorial [Building Your Own JavaScript Modal Plugin](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-your-own-javascript-modal-plugin)

The problem actually came at the end when I realized that he catches element by ID and I have multiple anchor tags that are supposed to open modal on click. I tried to change the ID to name but I realized I get the next code and only one works and I can't find the solution. I was searching for hours.

If you have suggestion how to catch elements differently or how to solve this one would be helpful.

```
var triggerButton = document.getElementsByName('trigger');

triggerButton[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
myModal.open();

triggerButton[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
myModal.open(); // if i put like this etc all my links work and etc.


});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fgtrdqyz/1/

Comment: There are typos in your post, and neat indenting helps. It's usually better to use a class value rather than name to select multiple elements.

Comment: @ArunPJohny when i put it that way it says in source code that the triggerButton isn't defined.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ah i had i typo when i was defining variable in first place i wrote triggerButton and it shold be triggerButtons. But nonetheles the solution actually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's best to use the attribute `class` for this:

```
<a class="trigger"> ... </a>
```

Then, in JS, get them with:

```
var triggerButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("trigger");
```

Then, loop through each one and add event listeners like you did:

```
for(var i = 0; i < triggerButtons.length; i++) {
    triggerButton[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        myModal.open();
    });
}
```

([Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fgtrdqyz/3/) is a working JS example.)

This is dynamic and is much easier than manually adding an event listener for each element.

If you wanted to do this in jQuery, this would be much easier. You can achieve this all with this one-liner:

```
$(".triggerButtons").click(function(){myModal.open();});
```

([Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fgtrdqyz/2/) is a jQuery example.)

Comment: The jQuery thing is unnecessary. Yes, it's less code to write. But requires 100kb library and is a lot less efficient.

Comment: @RobG Yes, it's less code and more intuitive (than the loop). It helps maintainability of code a lot! Also, I only provided it as a secondary *suggestion* in case jQuery was already being used. You wouldn't download the whole library just for this line.

Comment: Intuitive? Not really. If you know what the *$* function does (and since it's overloaded, it does different things when called with different types of argument) then it's not clear at all what the code does. A plain for loop doesn't have that issue. I fail to see how a for loop is less maintainable.

Comment: Yep i works fine as the solution of ArunPJohny at the top. But i am just a bit confused about one part if somebody can explain. 

I am storing a all class by name trigger to a var triggerButtons and then i say onclick triggerButtons open myModal, yet i dont put it anywhere in HTML?

Comment: @Mario I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but what I think you're wondering is that besides adding the `class` attribute, you don't have to edit your HTML.

Comment: @Jonathan i am not a JavaScript pro so dont wonder if my question is silly, but yea kind of something like that. Why i dont need to change HTML, because in the expamle i gave this guys had id="trigger" and class="triggerButtons". So now i was just wondering where is that triggerButtons gone. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to select what you want with the querySelectorAll function.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.trigger')
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[trigger]') 

with html like this

<a href="//blah" trigger="haha"></a>
```

"document.querySelectorAll" takes a CSS selector. So if you can select the item you want with a CSS query, you can select it with document.querySelectorAll().

Now, querySelectorAll returns an Array of items that match your query. If there are zero matches, you get an empty array. If you have 10 matches, they will all be in the array.

If you want to just match one element, you can use document.querySelector() (leave off the All). That will select just one element. And it works the same way, by passing it a CSS selector.